# aws sync with server folders which are present in local directory

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I had 10 subfolders named like 1-10 in my s3 bucket, but in my ec2 instance I had only 3 subfolders named as 1,2,3. So I want to sync (or cp) with s3 bucket only for to get these 3 folders data without having all 10 folders in my ec2. Is there any possibility to do something like this?

```
aws s3 sync s3://mybucket/ .  --include "*"
```

But i'm getting all 10 folders in my ec2 which are present in s3 bucket.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below command which will first exclude everything and then will only include those folders which you actually want :

```
aws s3 sync s3://mybucket/ .  --exclude "*" --include "1" --include "2" --include "3"
```

Comment: this wont works for me i tried this one. but thanks for your response

Comment: is there any way without using multiple includes,some thing with using bash commands

Comment: You can loop through it

Comment: find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n'  -exec  aws s3 sync s3://my-bucket/{}  .  \;
 something like this i tired, but its printing my folders & exiting the process